Terraform 0.13 Upgrade Failure
I am working on a very old terraform workspace and terraform init failed with
╷
│ Error: Invalid legacy provider address
│ 
│ This configuration or its associated state refers to the unqualified provider "aws".
│ 
│ You must complete the Terraform 0.13 upgrade process before upgrading to later versions.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid legacy provider address
│ 
│ This configuration or its associated state refers to the unqualified provider "datadog".
│ 
│ You must complete the Terraform 0.13 upgrade process before upgrading to later versions.
╵


Tried to following with tf doc
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/upgrade-guides/0-13
But when I run terraform 0.13upgrade
It said
Terraform has no command named "0.13upgrade".

To see all of Terraform's top-level commands, run:
  terraform -help

Wondering anyone knows if I missed any steps
The required provider is as below
  required_providers {
    datadog = "~> 2.20.0"
    azurerm = {
      # The "hashicorp" namespace is the new home for the HashiCorp-maintained
      # provider plugins.
      #
      # source is not required for the hashicorp/* namespace as a measure of
      # backward compatibility for commonly-used providers, but recommended for
      # explicitness.
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.12"
    }
    newrelic = {
      # source is required for providers in other namespaces, to avoid ambiguity.
      source  = "newrelic/newrelic"
      version = "~> 2.1.1"
    }
  }


Is it a coincidence that your providers file is almost identical to the one in the URL you shared? Also, which version of Terraform do you have installed? I recommend installing tfswitch to easily install and switch between different versions of Terraform. The command you need is available if you install Terraform 0.13.0; you likely have an earlier version, perhaps 0.12.0. https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/

Which version of terraform are you using at the moment?

our terraform is in version v0.12.31, and I am using v1.9.4 for terraform CLI

That will not work. You have to follow all the steps to upgrade from 0.12.x to 0.13.x etc. Here are all the steps you need to take: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/upgrade-guides/1-0.

According to Command: 0.13upgrade documentation, the command is available only in Terraform v0.13 releases.
I can confirm that the command terraform 0.13upgrade is not available when using a different Terraform version, such as v1.9.4:
Terraform has no command named "0.13upgrade".

To see all of Terraform's top-level commands, run:
  terraform -help


Thanks, I have used tfswitch to change my terraform to 0.13 and the command is there

@HanTang please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer.
